# Does it make sense to encrypt Wildfly Elytron Credential Storage file?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, elytron

In Wildfly I want to use Elytron Credential Storage to store passwords. I want to use password aliases instead of clear text.
Does it make sense to encrypt Credential Storage file with passwords? If I encrypt it, I have to keep the unencrypted password either in standalone.xml or in another unencrypted Credential Storage file.
So anyone who has access to the folder with credentials files has access to all passwords, regardless of whether we encrypt them or not.
The entire security is therefore based on limiting access to credentials files.
Am I not understanding something about this?
My description is based (not exactly) on the solution from the article: [how_to_configure_server_security/securely_storing_credentials](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/how_to_configure_server_security/securely_storing_credentials).
In my solution and the solution from the article there is the same problem, the secrets are encrypted with an unencrypted password so why should I encrypt them?
How should it be done correctly?